# Assigning covariate associated to spatial points to bigger set of spatial points?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system

I have two data sets with spatial points (in .csv format): data1 with 220 spatial points with latitude and longitude and data2 with 80 spatial points with latitude and longitude. For data2 I have one covariate indicated the genetic origin of each points. Spatial points in both datasets are not exactly the same.

I would like to assign the genetic origin for spatial points in data1. It seems that I need to define around each point in data2 a square (or other) to be able to associate a genetic origin at each points in data1.

Comment: Software? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Sorry I am using the R software